# Updating Mattermost from release-5.29 to release-5.33 brokes my volume data

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mattermost

I will like to know why is my db connection broking after I upgrade mattermost from 5.29 version to 5.33 release version. I was trying to figure out the issue in forums but i haven't catch this problem in another place.

This is my code base from my docker-compose, I am calling the images from the main repository of mattermost team edition at docker hub: https://hub.docker.com/r/mattermost/mattermost-team-edition

```yaml
version: "3.7"
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0.20
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: $PASSWORD
      MYSQL_DATABASE: $DB
      MYSQL_USER: $USER
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: $PASSWORD
    command: mysqld --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    volumes: 
      - ./volumes/db/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    networks:
      - my-network
  app:
    #image: mattermost/mattermost-team-edition:release-5.33
    image: mattermost/mattermost-team-edition:release-5.29
    container_name: mattermost-docker_app_1 
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/app/mattermost/config:/mattermost/config:rw
      - ./volumes/app/mattermost/data:/mattermost/data:rw
      - ./volumes/app/mattermost/logs:/mattermost/logs:rw
      - ./volumes/app/mattermost/plugins:/mattermost/plugins:rw
      - ./volumes/app/mattermost/client-plugins:/mattermost/client/plugins:rw
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    ports: 
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
      - MM_USERNAME=$USER
      - DB_PORT_NUMBER=$DBPORT
      - MM_DBNAME=$DBNAME
      - DB_HOST=$MY_IP_HOST
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=mattermost.mydomain.com
      - VIRTUAL_PORT=8000
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=mattermost.mydomain.com
      - MM_PASSWORD=$PASSWORD
      - MM_SQLSETTINGS_DRIVERNAME=$DNAME
      - MM_SQLSETTINGS_DATASOURCE=$DB_CONTAINER_URL_WITH_CREDENTIALS
    networks:
      - my-network
networks:
  my-network:
    external:
      name: my-network
```

Comment: Is the subject the volume data (as mentioned in the title) or the db connection (as mentioned in the post)?

Comment: I will go more for the db, i think in the new release the db structure could have change.